# shouldInterceptRequest on Android 4.4 KitKat

Tags: android, url, webview, android-4.4-kitkat

I have an App that uses custom schemes in Android WebViewClient's `shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url)` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)` to intercept requests in a web application and use a native library to fetch resources from elsewhere in `shouldInterceptRequest`. This has worked fine up until Android 4.4 KitKat, where Google has made some crucial changes to the webView component.

http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#URLs

Now the url received in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` suddenly gets invalid, looking like this; custom-scheme:////my.pathname.com/. First I suspected the extra slashes were because Android did not think the url were valid RFC3986, but in a series of resource fetches (css, js, images), the url starts off correct and suddenly changes to the invalid format. The webView in Android 4.3 kept the url correctly as custom-scheme://my.pathname.com/. It seems like the base url suddenly changes to '/' instead of 'my.pathname.com'.

Then my attention changed to the fact that the webView 4.4 migration guide talks about:

> If you call methods on WebView from any thread other than your app's UI thread, it can cause unexpected results. http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html#Threads

This also might be what I am experiencing, but I have not yet come up with a solution where I can use `runOnUiThread()` to fetch data with the native api and return it to the webView inside `shouldInterceptRequest`. Has anyone experienced something similar?

Here is a simplified version of my `shouldInterceptRequest` code:

```
    @Override
    public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        if (urlStartsWithKnownPrefix(url)) {
            UrlFetchResult fetchRes = api.fetchUrl(url);
            String charset = "utf-8";
            String mime = fetchRes.getMimetype();
            WebResourceResponse res = new WebResourceResponse(mime, charset, new ByteArrayInputStream(fetchRes.getResult()));
            return res;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: How are you referencing the content in your HTML? What is the expected and actual value for the URL that you recieve?

Comment: Resources are referenced relative, like; `<script src="js/script.js"></script>` and they do get fetched and shown correctly, but when I look at the DOM the base url is custom-scheme:////my.pathname.com/, which is invalid. Expected URL is custom-scheme://my.pathname.com/ which is valid.

Comment: How do you set the base URL and custom scheme?

Comment: The custom scheme is set in the url when I call loadUrl(url) on the webView to load the frontpage, I don't set the base url in code. I see that `loadDataWithBaseURL()` takes a baseUrl argument, but that method is used for data, not urls. Do I have to set the baseUrl explicitly for Android 4.4 WebView to work on custom-schemes? Everything works perfectly using http:// in the same webView, so Android is validating custom schemes different then http://.

Comment: Furthermore; if I override `onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)` and `onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)`, I get that it starts with url "custom-scheme://my.pathname.com/" and finishes with url "custom-scheme:////my.pathname.com/". Am I experiencing a bug here?

Comment: Just to confirm something, have you got the targetSDKVersion to 19 in your Android Manifest?

Comment: Yes. targetSdkVersion=19, minSdkVersion=11. Have tried lowering the targetSdkVersion, but the same error happens on a 4.4 android device.

Comment: Could you create a cut down example and put it on Github so I can have a look and play around with it / Nudge some people to see what could be the issue.

Comment: any solution if we are doing the redirects using iFrames in a webview, redirect happens on a HTTPS page with a custom protocol Ex: _customProrocol://_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using jquery-mobile by any chance? This sounds very similar to: [How can I use relative urls in ajax requests within trigger.io apps on Android 4.4 (kitkat)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20469514/how-can-i-use-relative-urls-in-ajax-requests-within-trigger-io-apps-on-android-4)

Comment: You are absolutely right. I ended up creating a patch for jQuery Mobile similar to this pull request: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/pull/6811/files . Also included some checking for extra slashes in the Android shouldInterceptRequest method. It's definitely not a beautiful solution, but it's the only thing that works right now.

Comment: what is the solution if custom protocol Ex: _customProtocol://_